# How to avoid 'Driver write request failed' error while writing large amount of data to h5 file?

Tags: python, samba, h5py

I'm trying to write a large amount of data to a h5 dataset using the following set of lines:

```
fpath = '/run/user/1002/gvfs/smb-share:server=path.to.server,share=Project/data.h5'
hf = h5py.File(fpath,'w')
hf.create_dataset('a', data=a)
dset = hf.create_dataset('b',(nrow,1),maxshape=(nrow,None),chunks=(nrow,1))
for i in range(ncol):
    dset[:,-1:] = b
    if i+1 < ncol:
        dset.resize(dset.shape[1]+1,axis=1)
hf.close()
```

The file at the location `fpath` is located in a shared folder and accessed through SMB protocol via Samba. Here `a` and `b` are numpy arrays `(dtype=float)` of shapes `(nrow,)` and `(nrow,ncol)` where `nrow = ~15000` and `ncol = ~50000`. When I run my code, I get the following error:

> OSError: Driver write request failed (file write failed: time = Wed
>   May  1 14:43:22 2019, filename =
>   '/run/user/1002/gvfs/smb-share:server=path.to.server, 
>   share=Project/data.h5', file descriptor = 11, errno = 95, error
>   message =  'Operation not supported', buf = 0x482ff88, total write
>   size = 124500, bytes this sub-write = 124500, bytes actually
>   written = 18446744073709551615, offset = 10879697965)

If I print the loop counter `print(i)`, I see that the loop reached the end so the error could be appearing at the `hf.close()` line.

I am thinking of breaking the files into multiple smaller files. Is there any other workaround to this error?

Additional information:

```
Operating system           Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS
Python                     v 3.5.2
h5py                       v 2.9.0
HDF5 (h5cc -showconfig)    v 1.8.16     
sys.maxsize                9223372036854775807
```

**UPDATE:**
I replaced the `resize` operation on the dataset by first storing the full data in a numpy array and then writing all the arrays into dataset in a single call to `create_dataset`. Later, I ran into another problem with the size of numpy array and had to reduce `ncol` by half and write the data in two steps.

It would still be nice if the error can be resolved for the iterative resizing of the dataset.

Comment: @DavisHerring Sorry for the confusion. The segmentation error was the exit message I got when I exited Python but I understand that it has nothing to do with the OSerror. I edited the title.